AG Grid save column order and sort order
I am using the AG Grid for React ver 32.x.x
I need the ability to store the column order and the sort order of the column in the localstorage. I have a code implemented to save and retrieve the column and sort order.
I have used props like onFirstDataRendered to load the new saved order but it does not work. It looks like AG Grid re-orders back to default column order as a final step which overwrites the saved order of columns.
If I put a setTimeout inside onFirstDataRendered to wait for 2-3 seconds before I load the saved column and sort order from local storage then it works.
Does anyone know how I can get this solved? thank you!
